# Why am I getting the wrong output although the code is correct?

Tags: r, rvest

I'm scraping [this](https://www.kariyer.net/is-ilanlari/#&kw=data%20scientist) website and sure that the code is correct for getting titles. But the output is not what I want.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.kariyer.net/is-ilanlari/#&kw=data%20scientist"
titles <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("div.col-9 a.link.position") %>% 
  html_text()
```

How do I get rid of this result?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I want what the job titles are. But the output seems like random.

Comment: It seems to me that `rvest` doesn't "understand" the url correctly. This snippet returns a count of all jobs (34 554 as of moment of writing)
`library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.kariyer.net/is-ilanlari/#&kw=data%20scientist"

 read_html(url) %>% 
 html_nodes(".count") %>% 
  .[[1]]
`. The result is the same as 
`library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.kariyer.net/is-ilanlari/"

 read_html(url) %>% 
 html_nodes(".count") %>% 
  .[[1]]
`
So it seems to me that the search query "data scientist" is not encoded correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url is the culprit. This worked for me as expected

```r
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.kariyer.net/is-ilanlari/kw=data%20scientist"

titles <- read_html(url) %>% 
    html_nodes("div.col-9 a.link.position")  %>% 
    html_attr("data-title")
```

Comment: Thanks! But why the code sometimes work and sometimes doesn't? I just tried [this link](https://www.kariyer.net/is-ilanlari/#&kw=veri%20analizi) but the output seems like random as I said before.

Comment: Hi @nerdakgul, have a careful look at the url - in my case as in the answer above the "#&" characters are missing after the last "/". As I have posted it, it works consistently for me - I get 37 titles which matches the 37 hits on the webpage.